# vs code 1.11 Path intellisense - does't work after update

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

have problem with path intellisense in vs code after update to version 1.11 - where can i turn on - in previous version works perfect ( no additional extension )

here is what about

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aqhvppkneog&feature=youtu.be

Comment: This is not a video streaming service, if you're having issues with your code then include it in the question and explain (in words!) what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on TS/JS support for VSCode. The problem you describe sounds like [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23962). You should still be able to trigger path intellisense using the `editor.action.triggerSuggest` keyboard shortcut.

VSCode 1.11 added better scoping for when quick suggestions are shown. The default settings however now disables quick suggestions inside of strings. To restore the previous behavior, try setting:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": true
}
```

This should restore quick suggestions for paths

Answer (score 0):

changing : 
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": true
}
solve problem ;-)